# jquery each function confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to update the contents of all elements with the id tag of "row_total" to "$0.00". I can't figure out how to use each() correctly. Whats written below only updates the first instance of #row_total.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#reset_row_totals").live('click', function() {


     $('#row_total').each(function() {
            $(this).html("$0.00");

          });          
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

heres a jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/uxLZm/3/

Answer (score 4):

It's the fact that you are reusing id's.  You can't have duplicate id's in HTML.  Instead, use classes.

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/MzrTd/

#### HTML

```
<td class='row_total'>$5.99</td>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#reset_row_totals").live('click', function() {
    
         
 $('.row_total').each(function() {
        $(this).html("$0.00");
    
      });          
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Many people (myself included) recommend delegate over live, but it'll work either way. But the OP is also not preventing default because they're not passing 'e' into the function. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uxLZm/14/

Comment: Thanks, @GregPettit.  Those coding mistakes tend to slip through when I'm copy and pasting the OPs code :\

Comment: NP, wasn't your fault. ;-) Nobody else fixed it in their responses either.

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple `<td>`s with the same id `row_total`. This is **invalid**. IDs are meant to be unique so when you let multiple elements have the same ID, things may not work as expected.

Instead, use a class which can be applied to multiple elements. Apply the class to each `<td>` which you want to reset and use the `.class_name` CSS selector: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PGuG/)

HTML:

```
<a href='#' id='reset_row_totals'>Reset Rows</a><br/><br/><br/>    
<table>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$5.99</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$3.50</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$32.00</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$9.99</td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset_row_totals").live('click', function(e) {
     $('.row_total').each(function() {
            $(this).html("$0.00");
          });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can only use one unique ID per page.  JavaScript will only see the first one.  Change it to a class and it should work.

Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxLZm/8/) with the change.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it only updates the first element with the ID of `row_total`. IDs are supposed to be just that, **unique** identifiers for elements.

Any selector for an ID will automatically return the first and only the first element with that ID. In this instance you need to use the class selector, and apply the class to the elements. I slightly edited your jsFiddle here >  http://jsfiddle.net/uxLZm/5/

Just as a matter of interest, you are implementing `$.each()` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your ID's are illegal html.  try this change to your html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$5.99</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$3.50</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$32.00</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='row_total'>$9.99</td></tr>

</table>


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#reset_row_totals").live('click', function() {


     $('.row_total').each(function() {
            $(this).html("$0.00");

          });          
    });
});
```